# Embedding values using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

As I m having incremental values of attributes  so i am ´following this method as you can see I hardcoded my attributes butI want to embed them in a loop..please  tell how can i do that.. I am not able to achieve that...Thank you..
 I m getting values in my dropdown from a json file in which i m having 20 attributes...When i click on particular value from dropdown ...the attributes related to that value are shown inside a list box..
My html

```
form name="myform" id="myForm">

    <select id="dropdown1"></select>
     <select id="listbox"></select>
    <!--  <input type="checkbox">-->
    <br>
```

```
     (document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];

            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1');







            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }
                /*  $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
                */

                $.each(usedNames, function(index, value) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        text: value['name'],
                        value: index
                    }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
                });

            /*    $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your List Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#listbox'); */



                $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                    $('#listbox').empty();

                    $('<option>', {
                      text: 'Select your List Option',
                        value: '',
                        selected: 'selected',
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    }).appendTo('#listbox');

                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                        if (value['name'] === selection) {
                            var optionHtml = '';
                            for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                                var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';
                            }
                            $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to generate the option elements as all the attributes are incremental. Try this:

```
var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
$.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
    if (value['name'] === selection) {
        var optionHtml = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
             var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
             optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5x8Lbo/)

Note that this also builds the HTML as a single string and appends it to the DOM once for better performance.

Comment: Hi..but now I m not getting values inside dropdown ..just attr001,attr002.....so on

Comment: Thanks alot for ur help...just one more thing right now what is happening as I select one vale from dropdown then in 2nd dropdown i m getting values but it is appended again and again  that is 20 times as i scroll down  i see same list of values coming over and over again ..but i want only once

Comment: That would depend on how you attach your event. http://api.jquery.com/one may help you. If you still have an issue with that it would be best to start a new question

Comment: I started a new question for this..will u please suggest something.. m still trying to figure out why my values are appended again and again    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495254/values-getting-appending-again-and-again?noredirect=1#comment60598652_36495254

Comment: i want to ask wht does -3 means here in substring

Comment: The -3 means that it will return the last 3 characters of the string